# How to select/match from MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table:

```
People
---------
ID | Name
---------
 1 | John
 2 | Sam
```

And I have another table:

```
Permissions
-----------
ID | Perm
-----------
 1 | View
 2 | Edit
 3 | Delete
```

These two tables are linked in a third table:

```
UserPermissions
----------------------
ID | User | Permission
----------------------
 1 |   1  |  1 (View)
 2 |   1  |  3 (Delete)
 3 |   2  |  1 (View)
```

I am trying to select a "total" permissions type table, where, if I wanted to get the permission for a user (Lets say user 2 (Sam)), I would get the following table:

```
UserPermissions
------------------
Permission | User
------------------
 1 (View)  |  2
 2 (Edit)  | NULL (Or some other nullish value)
 3 (Delete)| NULL
```

I have only recently started MySQL and I have no idea of what search terms I should be trying to get examples of similar queries. Does anyone know what type of queries I should be searching for / a way to implement this?

Comment: 1. Buy book. 2. Make a coffee/tea 3. Sit down. 4. Read it. 5. See the chapter on `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this for one user, you want a `left outer join`:

```
select p.*, up.user;
from Permissions p left outer join
     UserPermissions up
     on p.Permission = up.Permission and
        up.User = 2;
```

This works for one user.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're just looking for an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT P.Id, P.Perm, UP.Id User
FROM Permissions P
   LEFT JOIN UserPermissions UP ON P.Id = UP.Permission
```